# Why is Math.pow() showing loss of precision?

Tags: java, loops

why there is an error showing loss of precision although the answer in hackerrank is in integers only?when i am using double it is printing out like 2.0,5.0 which is not matching the output

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        /* enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = s.nextInt();
        int x, y;
        int p = 2;
        int q = 0;
        int i, j;
        for(j = 0; j < t; j++){
            y = 0;
            x = 0;
            int a = s.nextInt();
            int b = s.nextInt();
            int n  = s.nextInt();
            x = (a + Math.pow(p, q) * b);
            System.out.print(x);

            for(i = 1; i < n; i++) {
                y = (x + Math.pow(p, i) * b);
                System.out.print(y);
                x = y;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: what is the return type of `Math.pow()`?

Comment: I've formatted your code for readability because as posted your code formatting was poor. In the future I strongly recommend that you do this yourself. Formatting is very important because if your code is not in a standard accepted format, it's not very readable, and if it's not readable, it's not understandable, and this may reduce your likelihood of getting prompt decent answers.

Comment: The return type of `Math.pow` is double which you are assigning to an int variable `x`.

Answer (score 0):

When you're sure that `p` and `i` are always integers you could cast the `Math.pow(...)` call to Integer. Youre casting by adding `(int)` to the call:

`(a + ((int)Math.pow(p, q)) * b);`

The same goes for the second call of `Math.pow(...)`